# ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized with spring-data for mongo

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-data

I'm currently experiencing the following exception when my spring application starts:

```
2012-04-27 17:42:51,021 ERROR [main] com.hazelcast.impl.FactoryImpl - /10.188.31.125:54327 [dev] ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1fd0fafc: startup date [Fri Apr 27 17:42:46 CEST 2012]; root of context hierarchy
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1fd0fafc: startup date [Fri Apr 27 17:42:46 CEST 2012]; root of context hierarchy
       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:337) [spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:324) [spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:263) ~[spring-data-commons-core-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
       at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:364) ~[spring-data-commons-core-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
       at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:570) ~[spring-core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:247) ~[spring-data-commons-core-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
       at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:364) ~[spring-data-commons-core-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
       at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:570) ~[spring-core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:247) ~[spring-data-commons-core-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
       at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:165) ~[spring-data-commons-core-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
       at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:140) ~[spring-data-commons-core-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
       at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:65) ~[spring-data-commons-core-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.determineCollectionName(MongoTemplate.java:1494) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findAll(MongoTemplate.java:959) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
       at net.bigpoint.globalchat.hazelcast.MongoMapStore.loadAllKeys(MongoMapStore.java:59) ~[classes/:na]
       at com.hazelcast.impl.concurrentmap.MapStoreWrapper.loadAllKeys(MapStoreWrapper.java:131) ~[hazelcast-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
       at com.hazelcast.impl.FactoryImpl.checkInitialization(FactoryImpl.java:588) [hazelcast-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
       at com.hazelcast.impl.FactoryImpl.getOrCreateProxyByName(FactoryImpl.java:546) [hazelcast-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
       at com.hazelcast.impl.FactoryImpl.getMap(FactoryImpl.java:514) [hazelcast-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
       at com.hazelcast.impl.FactoryImpl$HazelcastInstanceProxy.getMap(FactoryImpl.java:240) [hazelcast-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:149) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactory
```

Background:

- my authenticationProvider for spring-security requires a hazelcast map
- hazelcast loads data at startup from a mapstore that is based on spring-data for mongo
- spring data wants to use the ApplicationEventMulticaster
- it's not there yet.

as far as i can tell the Multicaster is created when init() on the configurableApplicationContext is called, which seem to happen after the spring security stuff. (imediately after...)

can i force the the application context to set up the multicaster earlier or to set up hazelcast later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if its a Spring Security or general Spring issue but Spring Security classes are initialized before `init()` on the `configurableApplicationContext` is called (so before the `ApplicationEventMulticaster` is created).

I consider this an important issue because the only way to work around this is to remove dependency injection from my security implementations and get everything by hand from the application context when its used the first time (which I have done for now).

I'll probably raise a Jira issue for it.

Comment: Here we are in 2015 I have a similar issue. Did you raise the issue? Did it ever get fixed? Could you show your workaround?

Comment: my workaround was to inject the Spring application context itself instead of the bean and to use the getBean method of the context when the required dependency is used the first time. this avoids bean creation of the dependency at startup and does not result in the exception.